# How to build interface (for ipad or iphone) which similar to "Wall of Sound" app

Tags: ipad

Please check out "Wall Of Sound" app on iphone or ipad..

It has unlimited width and height, scrollable in all directions... and populates cells that come on screen randomly...

I want to build similar interface for an app..

If you can give me a clue on how to proceed, that would be greatly appreciated...

thanks,
Dan